# How to regex everything between colon and space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
product_id:WDC WD2500YS-18S revision:6C07 size(GB):232 state: ONLINE
```

and I need convert to anything else, like json:

```
{
  "product_id": "WDC WD2500YS-18S",
  "revision": "6C07",
  "size(GB)": "232",
  "state": "ONLINE"
}
```

I tried this `/([^:]+)/g`, but is not working because I need that the **WD2500YS-18S** be togetter with **WDC WD2500YS-18S**.

Comment: `/:[^]+ [^ ]+/` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the fact that the key doesn't contains spaces and check what follows with a lookahead.

```
/([^\s:]+):\s*([^:]+?)(?=\s+[^\s:]+:|\s*$)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution doesn't rely on lookaheads or lookbehinds, and utilizes the browser's built-in json parser to verify that the output is valid. It leverages the fact that the **keys** do not contain spaces. So `([^ ]+):` will find a key. We just wrap the key and value with quotation marks and let the built-in json parser do the rest.

```
var input = 'product_id:WDC WD2500YS-18S revision:6C07 size(GB):232 state: ONLINE';
console.log(JSON.parse(
  '{' +
  input.replace(/(^| )([^ ]+):/g,'","$2":"').substring(2) +
  '"}'
));
```

outputs:

```
{
product_id: "WDC WD2500YS-18S",
revision: "6C07",
size(GB): "232",
state: " ONLINE"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `size(GB)` is valid json key.

Comment: but `"size(GB)"` is a valid key.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/([^:]+):\s?([^:]+)(?:\s|$)/g` - [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uJ7lB1)

Comment: I need keys and values.

Comment: Amended; I was checking on the wrong string originally.

Comment: Amended again to allow for `state: ONLINE` having a space between the colon and the value.